# How to Run "npm install boombot" on Heroku Server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, installation, npm

I want to just run `npm install boombot` and edit the files via nano. Then, I want to run `node index.js`

I'm getting errors though when running `heroku run npm install boombot --app trooperbot`


[This](http://d.pr/i/dITm) is an image of me running it.

Thank you to anyone who can help me get up and running!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're thinking that Heroku is a server. It's not - it's a place where you deploy and run applications.

When you do `heroku run xxx` it runs the command on a brand new dyno that's already loaded with your app.  So "installing" something on that dyno will be to no avail, it will simply go away after you exit the dyno.  Read [How Heroku works](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works) to understand more about this.

So to approach solving your problem, you should declare package dependencies in `package.json` - see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm).